# VB Code to Close Open Subfolders in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

Outlook has an habit of opening sub-folders if an email has been sent to it automatically (through rules). There is no way to turn off this feature.

Does anyone have ideas for code that would periodically (say every 30 seconds), automatically collapse all subfolders within, say, the sent items folder?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for collapsing folders in the navigation pane.

The [Starting Outlook with all folders collapsed/expanded](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/595) states the following:

> To keep the mailbox collapsed even when a new message is being delivered, make sure that your Inbox and other folders that receive email (for instance by a rule) have been added to your Favorites list.